# Loading huge array in Internet Explorer 11 cause stack overflow

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer, stack-overflow

I have a (generated) page with a very large jagged array. It does not initialize in IE11; I get `SCRIPT28: Out of stack space` and `SCRIPT2343: Stack overflow at line: 1`. I have reduced the problematic page to the bare minimum with randomized data, and this is what it looks like:

```
<html><body>
    <div id="info">
        Loading...
    </div>
    <script>

        var d = [];
        var i = 0;

        d[i++] = [
        "XHC_14",
        0
        ];

        d[i++] = [
        "ZXS_26",
        "UVT_27",
        "QML_3149",
        "MJO_3150",
        15993327
        ];

        d[i++] = [
        "VKG_3156",
        "ZEA_3157",
        "KZG_3159",
        "MNA_3162",
        "AKX_3163",
        "KLK_3164",
        618601
        ];

        // more array initialization ...

        info.innerHTML = "<h1>Ready!</h1>"; // this will only show if the initialization succeeded
    </script>
</body></html>
```

The real file is ~500k lines, repeating the array initialization around ~14k times. Real file available here: [ie11_stack_overflow_problem.zip](http://www.rlvision.com/misc/ie11_stack_overflow_problem.zip)

It will only crash when the array initialization is large enough. I have triad all kinds of variation, including putting it inside a function to give it its own scope, to no avail. It works in all other browsers I tested, including IE8 on XP. My config is Win7 with IE 11.0.9600.17107 (fully updated).

Can anyone figure out why this is happening?

Comment: I don't think this is a runtime problem. I think that you've hit some limit in the compiler/interpretter. That's a pretty chunky source file. I might consider externalizing that data and trying to load it in via XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: I can't, since the point of the file is to be self contained (it is created by a [utility](http://www.rlvision.com/snap2html/) generates html based file listings)

Comment: I should add this: The jagged array seems to be part of the problem. If you just take one of the dir[i++] and multiply to the same size it does not happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That file is horrendous and is the kiss of death to both Visual Studio and Notepad++... and indeed IE11. You've blown up the interpreter.

I got this to work by using

```
JSON.serialize(d)
```

in another browser, then pasting the output as a string into the source file.

Then:

```
var jsonStr = '[[blablabla...I go on foreeeeeever]]';
var d=JSON.parse(jsonStr);
```

Now it loads in IE11.

So the solution is to write your data structure out as a JSON string and to parse it.

Comment: Interesting work-around. Although it does not give an answer to what is causing the crash. I wonder if it is a bug in IE11?

Comment: I think it's clear. Your code is blowing up the interpreter because it has run out of memory (stack space). It's debatable whether or not this qualifies as a bug or a design feature (I imagine that whichever stack is overflowing is probably constrained in size, by design). Is running out of memory a bug? Do both by Visual Studio and Notepad++ have the same bug? If you push hard enough, all browsers will have a limit. I think your file qualifies as a rather hard push.

Comment: (...and we always knew that IE is a bit rubbish anyway...).